# Spark or Storm (Trident)

Tags: apache-spark, redis, apache-storm

I am trying to scale a component in our system and thinking  about what should be a better way to go between Storm(Trident) and Spark.

So, we have 2 large sets which can contain upto Million of events stored inside redis cluster . Say S1 and S2.

**Now, we read a message from  a messaging queue(Kafka) and need to find all the elements which are present both in S1 and S2 (basically find **S1∩S2** ). Now for small sets Redis itself can do the intersection efficiently but we anticipate the size of these sets can be in million .**

To solve the above , we are looking to explore some distributed computation frameworks (namely Storm and Spark).

I have a little experience with basic Spouts and Bolts with Storm and think that it will not be able to work here efficiently as we will have to write the logic of intersection inside one of our bolts . Exploring if Trident can be of some use but looks to me it may not provide adequate .

On the other hand , **Spark provides RDD at its core which provide operations like intersection,union to be processed in parallel out of the box and my guess is we read a message from a messaging queue and submit a task to spark cluster which will read from the redis and compute S1∩S2 efficiently .So , I think Spark can be a good fit for our use case.
If both Storm and Spark can help I would be tilted to use Storm .**

Can anyone here provide some perspective .

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I am a committer at Flink and Storm, and work as a software engineer at Confluent focusing on Kafka Streams.*

I am not familiar with Spark details, but "intersect" sounds like a batch processing operator -- so I am not sure, if it will be available in Spark Streaming -- you should double check this (I assume you want to use Spark Streaming as you compare Spark to Storm). If you want to do batch processing, it sounds reasonable to go with Spark and exploit "intersect" operator.

Doing "intersect" in stream processing is different than for batch processing. However, it it basically a join operation and it should not be hard to implement this (as long as there is a proper join operator provided by the system).

As you mention that you will consumer message from Kafka, it might be worth to try out [Kafka Streams](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams), Kafka's stream processing library. Thus, you do not need to run an additional system. Kafka Streams offers rich DSL including sliding-window-joins.

If you want to go with a stream processing framework, I would rather use [Flink](http://flink.apache.org/) that is (IMHO) better than Storm (or Spark).

See also Confluent's Kafka Streams docs that are more detailed than Apache Kafka's docs of Kafka Streams: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/index.html

Comment: Thanks Matthias for the input ;)